# Why bittorrent need chunk hash

Tags: bittorrent

In the torrent file,every chunk(or piece) has a SHA1 hash.

Sure, this hash is used for verification because public network is unreliable.

In a private network, if all peers is reliable, should this hash been ignored, i.e skip chunk verification in client ?

Is there other consideration about using hash? e.g. network transfer error or software bug.

Comment: Why not? Verifying is cheap, even pre-SHA extension. Selectively disabling check depending on their source only introduce the risk of inconsistecies, which then require either tagging which block has been actually checked, or recheck the whole files.

Comment: I just want to save some CPU time if verifying is not needed

Comment: Try running `openssl speed sha1` on your PC. Even on a gigabit link, you would've only saved less than a second of CPU for each GB transferred.

Answer (score 2):

> In a private network, if all peers is reliable

Hardware is never 100% reliable. At large scale you're going to see random bitflips everywhere. TCP and UDP only have weak checksums that will miss a bit flip happening in flight every now and then. Memory may not be protected by ECC. Storage might not even be protected by checksums.

So eventually there will be some corruption go uncaught if data isn't verified.

Generic SHA1 software implementations already are quite fast and should be faster than most common network or storage systems. With [specialized SHA1 instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_SHA_extensions) in recent CPUs the cost of checksumming should become even lower, assuming the software makes use of them.

So generally speaking the risk of bitrot is not worth the very tiny decrease in CPU load. There might be exceptional situations where that is not the case, but it would be up to the operator of that specific system to measure the impact and decide whether he can accept bitrot to save a few CPU cycles.